# How to POST with 2 parameters using curl? REST. Java

Tags: java, json, rest, curl

I want introduce two String params (type and content) in the method "createPost".

I am using this line:

```
curl -i -u pepe:pepe -d 'type=Link&content=www' --header "Content-Type: application/json"  http://localhost:8080/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/user/post
```

But... that line introduces "type=Link&content=www" in the first parameter and leaves the second empty.

The method is this:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createPost(@FormParam("type") String type,  @FormParam("content") String content) { 
    postEJB.createPostUserRest(type, content);
    URI userURI = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().build();
    return Response.created(userURI).build();
}
```

How could I enter "Link" in the first and "www" in the second?

Many thanks to all and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

- To make sure that `curl` sends a `POST` request, use `-X POST`
- The method `createPost` expects `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`, which is not compatible with the `-d` option of `curl`. (Also, if I remember correctly, it's quite tricky to get things working with this media type, though certainly possible.). I suggest to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` instead, which is compatible with `-d` of `curl`, and easier to get things working.
- To pass multiple form parameters, you can use multiple `-d` options

To sum it up, change the Java code to this:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createPost(@FormParam("type") String type,  @FormParam("content") String content) { 
    postEJB.createPostUserRest(type, content);
    URI userURI = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().build();
    return Response.created(userURI).build();
}
```

And the curl request to this:

```
curl -X POST -d type=Link -d content=www -i -u pepe:pepe http://localhost:8080/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/api/user/post
```

Note that I dropped the `Content-Type: application/json` header.
The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
also implied by the way `-d` works,
and required by the way we changed the Java code above.